# Endpoint class in java and its use

Tags: java, web-services, ant, endpoint

I wrote a simple web service, then I came to know multiple ways to publish it.

1. the simplest way I thought was to use `Endpoint.publish`
2. the second one was saying `File->new web service` and then following the process. This I think requires axis2 installation
3. then I also came across ant and its build.xml and other similar files
4. I have not tried but I have heard about apache CXF framework too.

There could still be more ways to publish a web service but my question is

1. if we have endpoint class which does this for us why do we have so many options to achieve the same task? might be because service published with endpoint can never be republished?
2. and if so which is better or preferable under what situations? and what are differences between them?

thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged as WCF?   WCF is .NET, not Java.